# How to chain FluentApi validation

Tags: c#, validation, fluent

I have issue with FluentApiValidation.

Example:

```
RuleFor(x => x.IdentificationNumber)
    .Matches("^\\d{8}$").When(x => x.IsLegalType).WithMessage("This validation occurs only if this row is present, but not if other rows below are presented.")
    .Matches("^\\d{13}$").When(x => !x.IsLegalType).WithMessage("This validation always works")
    .Must((model, identificationNumber) => BeUniqueForIdentificationNumber(model)).WithMessage("This Validation Always works")
    .NotNull().WithMessage("This validation always works!");
```

Flag IsLegalType works correctly, but for some reason, the first chain block validation does not work, when I put other chains after.

If I comment all below chains and just put:

```
RuleFor(x => x.IdentificationNumber)
    .Matches("^\\d{8}$").When(x => x.IsLegalType).WithMessage("This validation occurs only if this row is present, but not if other rows below are presented.");
```

I believe that I need to change chaining in a better way.
Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a new `Rule` for each validation scenario.

```
     RuleFor(x => x.IdentificationNumber)
        .Matches("^\\d{8}$").When(x => x.IsLegalType).WithMessage("This validation occurs only if this row is present, but not if other rows below are presented.");
     RuleFor(x => x.IdentificationNumber)
         .Matches("^\\d{13}$").When(x => !x.IsLegalType).WithMessage("This validation always works");
     RuleFor(x => x.IdentificationNumber)
         .Must((model, identificationNumber) => BeUniqueForIdentificationNumber(model)).WithMessage("This Validation Always works");
     RuleFor(x => x.IdentificationNumber)
         .NotNull().WithMessage("This validation always works!");
```

Comment: No, for better code, it should be chained like this.

Comment: For readability I usually just make a new rule for each validation check. This makes it more clear for me. I don't know if you can have multiple validations with multiple messages on the same property with only one chain. According to your question you can't.